# Use Bootstrap 3 as well as Bootstrap 2

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded a html5 template named [Codester](http://www.html5xcss3.com/2013/05/codester-responsive-html5-theme.html). It works on top of Bootstrap 2.

But as of now the current version of Bootstrap is 3. And I am quite familiar with that so I want a method with which I would be able to work in bootstrap 3 but have that template run in bootstrap 2.

Or is there any simple process which will convert that template to bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this yourself. Download the template, and update it using this information:

http://getbootstrap.com/migration

http://www.bootply.com/bootstrap-3-migration-guide

There are tools that can help:

http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com

http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader

http://twitterbootstrapmigrator.w3masters.nl

But given that you need a template, I don't think this is what you want. It's probably not easy enough, as there are always problems that need a deeper level of knowledge to solve.

Tip: Ask the author of the template! (I cannot find contact details)

Comment: Instead of this is there any other way with which I don't change the template at all but use bootstrap 3 through out the other part of the website?

Comment: Yes, you can use Bootstrap 2 on pages where you use the template, and Bootstrap 3 on other parts of the website (where you don't use the old template).